# how do I call esnext in vim?

Tags: vim, jshint

after I install jshint as my vim plugin, when I write ecma6 feature, I get below output.

`'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option).`

maybe a foolish question, how could I switch to ecma6 checker pass `esnext` option in vim?

Comment: What is the plugin that you are using in vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just add the setting to your .jshintrc (in your home/project folder)

```
echo '{ "esnext": true }' > .jshintrc
```